What is a good website to find information regarding people with dissabilities?
I was checking WCAG2.1 to comply with a job related to it, and I read something interesting. For Guideline 2.1, Time-based media, to comply with AAA, sign language interpretation is provided for prerecorded audio.
My first thought was how many people are fluent in sign language rather than reading. I want to check that information on a website.
To comply with the AAA mentions that people who are deaf or hard of hearing are fluent in sign language, which helps to provide intonation, emotion, and interpretation.

I'll ad https://webaim.org/

Thanks for the suggestion.

Check with your national association for the deaf in your home country. They can give you an idea of the numbers, where you live.
I found this article on reading very interesting:
7 Ways Deaf and Hard of Hearing People Learn to Read Effectively

... it’s important to note that studies for decades have shown that
the average reading level of most young deaf adults after high school
is lower than that of their hearing friends. In addition, these
studies state that only 5% of deaf individuals reach a reading level
of 12th-grade reading or higher.

On a side note: While video captions are essential for deaf and hard of hearing, the vast majority of people who enjoy captioned video, do not have any hearing limitations. It's just easier to follow along when you can listen and read at the same time.
(I used to have a source on this, but I can't find it at the moment :-/ )
On a second side note: It's important to distinguish between Captions and Subtitles. Notice that WCAG refers to captions.

Thanks! this article will help me a lot.

W3C’s Web Accessibility Initiative has put together a bunch of resources to learn about accessibility.
For example, the It’s about people part, with stories and use cases.
The main goal is that of inclusion, and not to marginalise certain user groups even more. This is why the WCAG are not prioritised according to “number of people concerned”.
The World Health Organization has a page on disabilities, which also includes some facs, for example the World Report on Hearing.
But depending on the reach of the service to be designed, a global view might not make sense.
Websites like Statista might help, national statistical offices, and  Wikipedia sometimes has some information, or again local associations around the disability.

Thanks for the input Andy. I'll check the information.
